# Flip Normals with Geometry Nodes

Tags: normals, geometry, mathematics, geometry-nodes

I have geometry being created through geometry nodes and I am am trying to flip the normals on this duplicate geometry. However, it appears that normals are a read only attribute in the geometry nodes. Any ideas on how I can flip normals through geometry nodes?

Comment: It's not possible to modify mesh normals at the moment, but it's being talk about : https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes/16108/1519

Comment: Has there been any discussion on when those might be implemented?

Comment: It's not high priority right now it seems... You can follow the project tasks here : https://developer.blender.org/project/board/121/

Answer (score 5):

You can now use the [Flip Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/flip_faces.html) node.

[image]

You can also plug a boolean [field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html) into the *Selection* input to selectively flip faces.

For example :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to flip normals for any single face.
You just have to do several steps:

1. Detach selected face from mesh.
2. Put this face into convex hull.
3. Delete from convex hull all faces with normals orientation equal to normals orientation of the original face.

[image]

I already applied this solution in my answer here:
[Is extrude possible in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231344/is-extrude-possible-in-geometry-nodes/250863#250863)

Comment: can you apply this to every face in a mesh?